# Javascript: Cut string after last specific character

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm doing some Javascript to cut strings into 140 characters, without breaking words and stuff, but now i want the text so have some sense. so i would like if you find a character (just like ., , :, ;, etc) and if the string is>110 characters and <140 then slice it, so the text has more sense. Here is what i have done:
where texto means text, longitud means length, and arrayDeTextos means ArrayText.
Thank you.

```
//function to cut strings
function textToCut(texto, longitud){
    if(texto.length<longitud) return texto;
    else {
        var cortado=texto.substring(0,longitud).split(' ');
        texto='';
        for(key in cortado){
            if(key<(cortado.length-1)){
                texto+=cortado[key]+' ';
                if(texto.length>110 && texto.length<140) {
                    alert(texto);
                }
        }
      }
    }
    return texto;
}

function textToCutArray(texto, longitud){
    var arrayDeTextos=[];
    var i=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        arrayDeTextos.push(textToCut(texto, longitud));
        texto=texto.replace(arrayDeTextos[i],'');
    }while(arrayDeTextos[i].length!=0)
        arrayDeTextos.push(texto);
    for(key in arrayDeTextos){
        if(arrayDeTextos[key].length==0){
          delete arrayDeTextos[key];
        }
  }
    return arrayDeTextos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the string into sentences, then check the length of the final string before appending each sentence.

```
var str = "Test Sentence. Test Sentence";
var arr = str.split(/[.,;:]/) //create an array of sentences delimited by .,;:

var final_str = ''
for (var s in arr) {
    if (final_str.length == 0) {
        final_str += arr[s];
    } else if (final_str.length + s.length < 140) {
        final_str += arr[s];
    }
}

alert(final_str); // should have as many full sentences as possible less than 140 characters.
```

Comment: Ooops, was appending index values. Fixed.

Comment: I think i didn't explain well. The alert gives me the text without . but what i need is if the text is larger than 110 characters and shorter than 140, and finds some point, coma, or things like that, then, the string must be cut cut in that place.

Comment: For example this text: "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit". If we supose where it says ament(,) the string were larger than 110 characters and shorter than 140, then the string must be cut to this: Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,

Answer (score 0):

I think Martin Konecny's solution doesn't work well because it excludes the delimiter and so removes lots of sense from the text.

This is my solution:

```
var arrTextChunks = text.split(/([,:\?!.;])/g),
    finalText = "",
    finalTextLength = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arrTextChunks.length; i += 2) {
    if(finalTextLength + arrTextChunks[i].length + 1 < 140) {
        finalText += arrTextChunks[i] + arrTextChunks[i + 1];
        finalTextLength += arrTextChunks[i].length;
    } else if(finalTextLength > 110) { 
        break; 
    }       
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/3or7j50q/3/

I'm aware of the fact that the `i += 2` part does only make sense for "common" usages of punctuation (a single dot, colon etc.) and nothing like "hi!!!?!?1!1!".

Answer (score 0):

Should be a bit more effective without regex splits.

```
var truncate = function (str, maxLen, delims) {
    str = str.substring(0, maxLen);

    return str.substring(0, Math.max.apply(null, delims.map(function (s) {
        return str.lastIndexOf(s);
    })));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, you can see how it works here: http://regexper.com/#%5E(%5Cr%5Cn%7C.)%7B1%2C140%7D%5Cb

```
str.match(/^(\r\n|.){1,140}\b/g).join('')
```